# Getting "The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1" while building an image from dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, requirements.txt

here is my requirements.txt

```
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
cachetools==5.2.0
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
Flask==2.2.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.0.2
google==3.0.0
google-api-core==2.10.2
google-auth==2.14.1
google-cloud-pubsub==2.13.11
googleapis-common-protos==1.57.0
greenlet==2.0.1
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.4
grpcio==1.51.1
grpcio-status==1.51.1
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==5.2.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
NotFound==1.0.2
proto-plus==1.22.1
protobuf==4.21.12
psycopg2==2.9.5
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
requests==2.28.1
rsa==4.9
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
SQLAlchemy==1.4.45
urllib3==1.26.13
Werkzeug==2.2.2
zipp==3.11.0
```

here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./


# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "-u", "main.py"]
```

- done all the versions upgrades and downgrades of the installed modules
- tried with python 3.8.2.final.0 && 3.10 python interpreter
- what to do? any leads would be appreciated..!!

Comment: what's the full error you're seeing?

Comment: A way to check and debug this is to do the pip install step manually. Temporarily comment it out from your Dockerfile, let it build the image, then try running a container and doing the pip install manually. You'll be able to see the errors more easily. Also, it may also be that it's failing to install one of the packages, so you could try installing them one by one to see which package is failing to install.

Comment: In any case, "returned a non-zero exit code" is the generic error when most command fails, not specific to pip. There's probably more info in either the Docker or the pip logs... which you need to find and post here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to install your Python dependencies in a Docker environment and I identified an error while installing the `psycopg2` package.

The reason is this package relies on two core dependencies:

- `libpq-dev`
- `gcc`

But the Docker base image you use `python:3.10-slim` does not contain these core dependencies natively. You must declare their installation from your Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install core dependencies.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libpq-dev build-essential

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "-u", "main.py"]
```

UPDATE: Investigation steps

1. Connect to Docker container running `python:3.10-slim` image:

```bash
docker run -it --rm python:3.10-slim /bin/bash
```

2. Write `requirements.txt` file with adapted content:

```bash
cat << EOF > requirements.txt
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
cachetools==5.2.0
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.6
Flask==2.2.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==3.0.2
google==3.0.0
google-api-core==2.10.2
google-auth==2.14.1
google-cloud-pubsub==2.13.11
googleapis-common-protos==1.57.0
greenlet==2.0.1
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.4
grpcio==1.51.1
grpcio-status==1.51.1
idna==3.4
importlib-metadata==5.2.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
NotFound==1.0.2
proto-plus==1.22.1
protobuf==4.21.12
psycopg2==2.9.5
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
requests==2.28.1
rsa==4.9
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
SQLAlchemy==1.4.45
urllib3==1.26.13
Werkzeug==2.2.2
zipp==3.11.0

EOF
```

3. Run `pip` command:

```bash
pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

4. Catch first error related to missing `libpq-dev` package
5. Installing `libpq-dev`:

```bash
apt update -y && apt-get install -y libpq-dev
```

6. Run `pip` command again
7. Catch second error related to missing `gcc` package

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked..!! it will be very helpful if you can share how you got to know this error. it will be a great help

Comment: @ShivamKumar if it can help I updated my answer with the steps I followed for investigation

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I put wrong version for some packages in the `requirements.txt` file! Just take a look deeply in the error message, you will find the package with mismatch version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are running the Docker build command from the correct directory where the requirements.txt file is located. You can use the cd command to change the directory before running the Docker build.

> cd /path/to/your/project
> docker build -t your_image_name .